# Remote mysql connection issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a remote connection using this PHP script from my website to another website of mine. But it is showing errors which says *hostname is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serve*

Please let me know what I am missing and also tell me if there any other way to access remote MySQL data using a PHP script.

```
$connect=mysql_connect("hostname","user","password")or die(mysql_error().'Our database is currently down for updates, please check back later.');
```

Comment: Probably your hostname is `localhost`. You also have to give an valid username and password..

Comment: hostname should be changed to the host of your mysql server - unless you are accessing this remotely you should try `localhost`, otherwise use the ip address where your mysql is.  You will also need to change the username and password to ones you have set up with access to the db.  [More info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Yes I am using a remote host and hence the IP of that mysql. And also the username and password have been given there correctly.

Comment: 1) do not use mysql_* libraries because they're deprecated 2) The answer to this question is in the question itself: the user specified cannot connect remotely to the database. Grant the proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly allow the mysql user to connect from the host. For example CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'; will allow the user jeffrey to connect only from localhost.

You can do that via sql commands or phpmyadmin, check the users tab.

Comment: The host is not local. I am using the IP of the another website of which I am accessing the mysql.

I have a website Abc.com and I want to access the SQL of pqr.com then I think i should use the IP of pqr.com as the hostname. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to explain. Check the rights of the user you are trying to connect with.

Comment: I have granted all rights to the user while creating and assigning it to the DB.

Comment: I just noticed that you edited the first comment. In case you want to connect from abc.com to the mysql of pqr.com, the host should be the IP of the abc.com. It means that you do allow that user from that IP to connect to this mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the mysql user access to your database from the host where the script is running. So if your mysql server is on host server, and the script runs on machine dev, your grant statement would look something like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'dev' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: How do i do that? I am having a shared hosting and don't have the root permission.

BTW while creating and assigning the user, i have already granted all permission to the user.

Comment: To clarify, you should enter this statement in mysql, not on a unix command line. You need mysql grant privileges for that. If you don't have those, you should ask your admin to run this.

Comment: I am a cpanel user and have already granted the permission to the user while assigning it to the DB.

Answer (score -1):

Does your MySQL database allow remote access to connect? If not, change the configs.

**UPD**
[Tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) for changing mysql remote access configs

Comment: this should really be a comment, otherwise expand on it and make it into a real answer (ie how would you change the configs, which configs do you change)

Comment: I am on a shared web hosting. is it possible to do that with those rights?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have enough rep to comment questions, but i'm working on it

Comment: @AmirNasir you can contact your hosting administrator to make such changes to configs (though he may reject). Also you can allow only your website (or IP address) to connect remotely to your database.

**UPD:** _FYI_ you can read on how to change mysql remote access [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: Thanks @NafFiQ, but to make those changes I'll either have to have root access or my web hosting provider should be kind enough to do that. Isn't there any other way to do that?

Comment: @AmirNasir if mysql doesn't accept remote connections then this may be impossible. Or you can write some API for your database server (PHP or whatever) but be careful with security issues.